# delete listbox data in winform C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, listbox

I want to delete data from  database using aa ListBox in a C# WinForm application. I am trying this code but it is not working. Please tell me how can I delete data from ListBox

it is giving me this  error

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

```
string i= listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); 

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

con.Open();

SqlCommand CmdAddProof = new SqlCommand("delete from Tb_IdProof where PID='" + i+ "'", con);

CmdAddProof.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

CmdAddProof.ExecuteNonQuery();

textBox1.Text = string.Empty;

ShowProof();

con.Close();
```

Comment: And what's not working?

Comment: data is not deleting from from listbox

Comment: Is `PID` an `int`?  If so you might want to remove the single quotes `'` around the paramter in your command text.

Comment: You forgot to add a line to do that, for example like this one: `listBox1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: Try removing the single quotes as so `new SqlCommand("delete from Tb_IdProof where PID=" + i, con);`

Comment: @oleksii its give me error
 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

Comment: Stating somewhere that this is a data bound ListBox might avoid some confusion.

Comment: @MartinParkin gives error 
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
Incorrect syntax near 'System.Data.DataRowView'.

Comment: @Kazuo  i wanna to delete data from database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PID` is an `int` data type you will get a data conversion error because you are passing in your ID value as a `varchar` not an `int`.

Removing the single quotes from your command text will fix it:

```
SqlCommand CmdAddProof = new SqlCommand("delete from Tb_IdProof where PID=" + i, con);
```

**Edit following further comments by user**

As it transpires that the `ListBox` is actually data bound, you are receving the error because the `SelectedItem` property is giving you back a `DataRowView` instead of a value.

You will need to obtain the value for the `PID` column from the `DataRowView` object before you call your `SqlCommand`.

Comment: thanks for the solution I obtain the value from the DataRowView object and it is working well now

Answer (score 0):

Is it manually generated or data bound;

If manually generated use

```
listBox1.Items.Remove(i);
```

If databound you need to refresh your binding in that case.

Regards Jan.

Comment: add: I think i missunderstood the question; does it not delete from the database or doesnt it remove the ui element?

Comment: That is point - it is clearly data bound and he wants an answer that takes this into account...

Comment: it is giving me error 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

Comment: @Killercam i wanna to delete data from database using this listbox

Comment: It is clear from the message that you need to remove the single quotes from your SQL expression. `new SqlCommand(String.Format("DELETE FROM  Tb_IdProof WHERE PID={0}", i), con);`. This will fix your issue...

Comment: @user2667382 that error prolly occurs because youre using the ToString Method and it converted a DataRowView item to System.Data.DataRowView ... try using Convert.ToIn32(listBox1.SelectedValue)

Comment: @Killercam 

now it is the error 
The multi-part identifier "System.Data.DataRowView" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can improve:

- Use parametrised command
- Do not mix code and data
- Read about SQL injection attacks
- Add error handling code
- Separate db code from UI clean up code into two methods

This is likely to fix your problem.

**EDIT**

If you use parametrised command, you pass it a type, so that the driver knows how to handle and escape the type. When you embed a variable into a query, a `.ToString()` method gets called. There can be many bugs due to incorrect assumption that string representation corresponds to what you expect it to be. In this case, this will work. But! In other cases it may not work. Such bugs are really difficult to debug, as they appear only in certain cases.

You may choose to say that application is only going to speak to a local server. Never ever it is going to be exposed to the network. Then you change your job and application suddenly becomes very successful and exposed to the Internet. And guess what?

If only you had applied defensive codding by default, you could have saved yourself from many troubles.

Always assume that environment is hostile, user input is evil and trust no one. Feel free to disagree, you have been warned.

Comment: How does this answer his question? "Read about SQL injection attacks", why, his app may be non-network based, non-web enabled - are users of software going to start hacking there own databases? I hate this blanket comment so much...